# How to Store Histogram Values using SparseMat on OpenCV

Tags: opencv, histogram, sparse-matrix

Calculating and storing the dense histogram matrix for my image processing operations is inefficient. ( there is no many differences on the image's color ) For the sake of efficiency, I want to use a sparse matrix. I could not find any example that stores histogram values on sparse matrix.

How can I use a **SparseMat** for storing histogram values using OpenCV? Please, can you give me a code example or link that I can read?

Answer (score 0):

With opencv api: output histograms could be dense or sparse matrices.
You need to give reference to specific histogram matrix in argument of `void  calcHist(..)` method.

Here is the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html).